# Is there a way to change the weather in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to change the weather in Minecraft in Creative Mode? All it does is rain all the time. It's rained for three days. Is there a way, mods included, that can change it?

Comment: the method is the same, but the question is different, one is for server control and the other is client side, but yes it's a bit duplicate

Comment: doesnt NEI change weather too?

Comment: Addendum to the answers: You have to have cheats enabled to use commands. If you don't want to enable cheats but don't mind installing mods (for some odd reason...), please specify that; I'm sure people will be more than willing to help :)

Comment: @fbueckert Hmm. It's arguably a duplicate: the commands are "server commands" but there is a single player feature to let you use server commands in single player. The difference is that you have to know how to enable them in single player, and that lots of people don't *know* the commands are the same and so won't go looking for server commands. I'm on the fence.

Comment: There's really only one question, "How do I change the weather in minecraft"; splitting it into two questions, one for singleplayer, one for multiplayer, accomplishes little. These are clearly duplicate questions, and the other one should be broadened if that is felt necessary.

Comment: ... and I've decided to resolve this by flagging the older question as a duplicate of the newer one.

Answer (score 16):

To change the weather in Minecraft, use the `/weather` [command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command).

The syntax is `/weather [type] [seconds]`. When you use it you set the weather to the specified *type* for the number of seconds you told it. The type can be either `clear`, `rain`, or `thunder`.

This command is only accessible if you have cheats enabled for your single player world (chosen when you made it) or are a server operator. If you're playing single player and don't have cheats on, you can turn them on temporarily: use the Open To LAN menu and make sure you choose cheats in the LAN options before starting the LAN game. Turning on cheats this way will only last until you quit the world and reopen it. (To more permanently turn on cheats you need a save editor like NBTedit.)

Comment: You can also set those commands in a Command Block as an OP in creative mode.

Comment: @RichardA Sure, but why?

Comment: Just an idea. We're using it on my server because of Forestry.

Comment: @RichardA Ah. Yeah, as a convenience on a server that makes sense!

Comment: Should work on the clientside too.

Comment: @RichardA Yeah, but clientside it's simpler to just type `/toggledownfall` than it is to set up a command block and go find the button every time you want it, which is why I was wondering about the point. On a server where you want non-OPs to be able to change the weather it makes a lot of sense, but on singleplayer it's not much benefit. It would definitely work just fine though, yeah.

Comment: "Yeah, but clientside it's simpler to just type /toggledownfall than it is to set up a command block and go find the button every time you want it" That's very true.

Comment: You can also consider using a daylight sensor with command blocks so it always stays day/night.

Comment: @Marco What does that have to do with the weather?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie hmm.. thats a very good question indeed.

Comment: `/toggledownfall` no longer exists in 1.13

Comment: @pppery Ah. Six years of development will do that. I don’t have time to edit at the moment; do you want to propose an edit to fix it?