# How do you make rain stop in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I try commands for rain I checked controls it was Button 14 where is Button 14?

Comment: [This queston](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120479/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-weather-in-minecraft?noredirect=1&lq=1) would have been a better duplicate to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
/weather clear
```

If you want stop the rain for ever put the command into an repeating command block

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Without cheating, you can sleep in a bed. If it's day, you'll have to wait until it's night to sleep.

Or you can run `/weather clear` to make it stop raining immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The command:

```
/toggledownfall
```

will toggle the current weather. If the weather is rainy, it will stop raining, and if the weather is clear it will start raining.

You can also use

```
/weather clear
```

to clear the weather, no matter the current status. You can put this on a clock or use a repeating command block to keep the weather clear constantly.