# How do I change time and weather of my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What command do I use to change the weather or time? I've tried everything on the wiki but I could not get it to work. I tried doing `/changeweather` because the forums has suggested the command, but it didn't work.

Comment: Combining two questions, both of which have already been answered, into one does not make that one not a duplicate. In this case, when there are already questions for [changing the time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79906/is-there-a-way-to-change-time-in-creative-mode-of-minecraft) and [changing the weather](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120479/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-weather-in-minecraft), this question adds nothing and should be closed as a duplicate of both. I flagged it as a duplicate of the time one arbitrarily.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `/time` command. The syntax is such:

```
/time <mode> <value>
```

Both parameters are needed. Examples:

`/time set day` will make the time morning,

`/time set night` will make it night,

`/time set 6500` will make it noon.

To change the weather, use the `/weather` command. The syntax is such:

```
/weather <mode> <time>
```

Where the second parameter, time, is optional. Examples:

`/weather clear` will the weather sunny,

`/weather rain` will make it rainy,

`/weather clear 1000` will make it sunny for at least 1000 seconds.

Comment: @YourWorstNightmare please consider marking this question as accepted by clicking on the gray check mark next to this answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
/time set [number/day, night, etc.]

/weather set [weather; clear, rain, etc.]
```